# Pasting 'tab' to a UITextView

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uitextfield, uitextview

In the simulator I pasted into a `UITextView`. I wasn't aware I still had some objective-c code on my pasteboard, so the pasted text included multiple lines and some tabs.

I was surprised to see that the text field suddenly became multiline (it looked awful obviously, since the view is tall enough for only 1-2 lines).

I have also experienced in `UITextField`s that pasting in the same formatted text messes with my implementation of `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:` which I use to size some views correctly.

Can anyone shed some light on what is happening, and whether I need to code around this possibility? On the device itself, does the OS somehow handle the issue? I am also going to try hosting the same piece of text on a website to see if copying and pasting from within the device exhibits the same behavior.

I really hope it is just a limitation of the simulator and copying from an external environment.